# Show that the number $a_{n}=\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+...}}}$, is irrational for every positive integer n.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Define $a_{n}=\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2+...}}},\quad n=1,2,...$ where the radical contains $n$ twos.

Provide a recursive definition of $a_n$ and then show that the number $a_n$ is irrational for every positive integer n.

This is what I have so far-

$$a_0=\sqrt{2}, \quad a_{n+1}=\sqrt{2+a_n}$$

Assume $a_{n+1}$ is rational. Then

\begin{align*}
a_{n+1}&=\frac{b}{c} \quad grd(b,c)=1\\
(a_{n+1})^2&=\frac{b^2}{c^2}\\
2+a_n&=\frac{b^2}{c^2}\\
(2+a_n)c^2&=b^2 \quad =>(2+a_n)\big|b^2\\
\end{align*}

Is this correct so far? I am not sure what the next step is or if I am even on the right path?

Comment: If $a_{n+1}\in \mathbb Q$ then $a_n=a_{n+1}^2-2 \in \mathbb Q$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a potentially easier way to go about this.

You have your recursive formula $a_{n+1}=\sqrt{a_{n}+2}$ as you defined already

Let us now proceed by induction on n

We know already that $\sqrt{2}$ is irrational, so the base case holds.

Now, suppose that for some $n\in\mathbb{N}$ that $a_n$ is irrational.

Now suppose for the sake of contradiction that $a_{n+1}$ is rational.

This would imply 2+$a_n$ is rational, which in particular implies that $a_n$ is rational. This is a contradiction.

Answer (score 2):

Using induction we suppose that $a_n$ is irrational. Suppose now that $a_{n+1}$ is rational. Then $a^2_{n+1}=2+a_n$, therefore $a_n$ is rational, contradiction.

Comment: Unless they're all rational. You should at least mention the base case

Comment: @vrugtehagel that is $\sqrt{2}$, which is trivial.

Comment: $a_n=2\cos\pi/2^{n+1}$, as can easily be shown by induction. But $\cos\pi/m$ for integer $m>2$ can only be rational for $m=3$ (consider the equation $\cos m\,y=-1$, the LHS is a polynomial in $\cos y$ with leading coefficient $2^{m-1}$, so the denominator has to be a power of two).

Comment: @vrugtehagel ok, my bad, sorry for this.

Comment: I think it's legitimate to omit discussing an obvious and trivial base case like this. OP ought to be able to complete the proof on their own.

Answer (score 1):

I think an easier proof can be formed by using induction. We already know that $a_0$ is irrational. So suppose that $a_n$ is irrational. Then it is easy to show that $a_{n+1}=\sqrt{2+a_n}$ is also irrational.